# Error found in question view calculation

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I think the total number of views to question is being calculated wrong...

[this question for example](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/16/can-a-youtube-video-be-submitted-as-prior-art)

Here no of views is still 1, but it already have more than 8 up votes.

That means there is error in view calculation.

---

**Screenshot of question is added below**

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: Now the views are being updated ( Bug solved )

Comment: Good catch tho, and this shows that you're involved in the site and that you want it do well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View counts for questions are heavily cached; they aren't updated in real time, so the count won't be 100% accurate at any time that you view it. Given that the question was only a couple of hours old, you just viewed it before the count had a chance to refresh.

Comment: I would also note that this caching effect is *much* more pronounced when the site is very young and does not yet have a lot of traffic. You will hardly notice it at all once the site gets going.